Keycloak admin client user update missing method
I use 'org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:26.0.2' in a Spring-Boot project and I want update a user attribute at a realm.
import org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.UsersResource;
import org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation;
import org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak;

...

        Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(
                "https://my-server.org:9443",
                "master",
                cliUser,
                cliPassword,
                "admin-cli");

        UsersResource userResource = keycloak.realm("my-realm").users();
        List<UserRepresentation> foundUsers = userResource.searchByEmail("pz@mail.hu", true);
        Optional<UserRepresentation> user = foundUsers.stream().findFirst();
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            Map<String, List<String>> attribs = user.get().getAttributes();
            attribs.get("language").set(0,"en");
            user.get().setAttributes(attribs);
            try {
                userResource.update(user) //No method with name update
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

I don't understand why update method missing. Please help me. Thanks for suggestions.

Ok, I found the missing method:
        Optional<UserRepresentation> user = foundUsers.stream().findFirst();
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            Map<String, List<String>> attribs = user.get().getAttributes();
            if (attribs.containsKey("language")) {
                attribs.get("language").set(0,"hu");
                userResource.get(user.get().getId()).update(user.get());
            }
        }

